# Save changes to a file AWK/SED

Tags: bash, shell, sed, awk

I have a huge text file delimited with comma.

```
19429,(Starbucks),390 Provan Walk,Glasgow,G34 9DL,-4.136909,55.872982
```

The first one is a unique id. I want the user to enter the id and enter a value for one of the following 6 fields in order to be replaced. Also, i'm asking him to enter a 2-7 value in order to identify which field should be replaced.

Now i've done something like this. I am checking every line to find the id user entered and then i'm replacing the value.

```
awk -F ',' -v elem=$element -v id=$code -v value=$value '{if($1==id) {if(elem==2) { $2=value } etc }}' $path
```

Where $path = /root/clients.txt

Let's say user enters "2" in order to replace the second field, and also enters "Whatever". Now i want "(Starbucks)" to be replaced with "Whatever" What i've done work fine but does not save the change into the file. I know that awk is not supposed to do so, but i don't know how to do it. I've searched a lot in google but still no luck.

Can you tell me how i'm supposed to do this? I know that i can do it with sed but i don't know how.

Comment: If this is a "huge file", then using a real database instead of something you "roll yourself" will in the long run be a much better solution... In the short term, use the `-i` flag with `sed` for "in place substitution".

Comment: well, it's not huge, also it's for a university project. The problem is that i really can't understand how to use sed. It's so complicated..Also it's not a hardcoded field i have to change it depends on the user input...

Comment: Are you doing this inside a `bash` program or some such? How do you get the values `$code`, `$element` and `$value`?

Comment: yes. i'm using minix & bash 4.2

Answer (score 3):

Newer versions of GNU awk support inplace editing:

```
awk -i inplace -v elem="$element" -v id="$code" -v value="$value" '
    BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," } $1==id{ $elem=value } 1
' "$path"
```

With other awks:

```
awk -v elem="$element" -v id="$code" -v value="$value" '
    BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," } $1==id{ $elem=value } 1
' "$path" > /usr/tmp/tmp$$ &&
mv /usr/tmp/tmp$$ "$path"
```

NOTES:

1. Always quote your shell variables unless you have an explicit reason not to and fully understand all of the implications and caveats.
2. If you're creating a tmp file, use "&&" before replacing your original with it so you don't zap your original file if the tmp file creation fails for any reason.
3. I fully support replacing Starbucks with Whatever in Glasgow - I'd like to think they wouldn't have let it open in the first place back in my day (1986 Glasgow Uni Comp Sci alum) :-).

Comment: +1 for not supporting Starbucks! `:P` Artisan Roast?

Comment: @jaypal neighborhood greasy breakfast cafes that make their coffee by running steam through milk. Can't be beat :-).

Answer (score 2):

`awk` is much easier than `sed` for processing specific variable fields, but it does not have in-place processing.  Thus you might do the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
code=$1
element=$2
value=$3
echo "code is $code"
awk -F ',' -v elem=$element -v id=$code -v value=$value 'BEGIN{OFS=",";} /^'$code',/{$elem=value}1' mydb > /tmp/mydb.txt
mv /tmp/mydb.txt ./mydb
```

This finds a match for a line starting with `code` followed by a comma (you could also use `($1==code)`), then sets the `elem`th field to `value`; finally it prints the output, using the comma as output field separator. If nothing matches, it just echoes the input line.

Everything is written to a temporary file, then overwrites the original.

Not very nice but it gets the job done.

Comment: +1: `GNU awk 4.1` supports [in-place](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Extension-Sample-Inplace) processing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've used it and it worked. But i really want to understand how it works. What does "1" do in {$elem=value}1?

Comment: @pipis - the `1` is `awk` shorthand for `if (1==1) print;` because `1` is the same thing as `true`, and when no command is given `awk does the default action, which is to print. It is a handy shortcut, and great for making you look really clever .